# Implementing multiple server support PHP script

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql

About 6 months ago I started a website that converts videos to various formats.

In the past few weeks the website's traffic has increased over 300% and now I need to balance the load so to speak.

Right now I have one main server which is getting a high server load from too many ffmpeg conversions. What I want to do is add a second and third server into the mix, however the script isn't built to do this.

I'm wondering if there's a way to set up a domain to dynamically select from server IPs. This way I could install the exact same configuration I have on my main server on all subsequent servers and just leave the script as it is.

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here's the reverse proxy I've set up. On the other servers I have set up a virtualhost with the same name "main.website.com", but for some reason when the pages load there's no CSS. Looking at the server logs it seems like the server I'm proxying to isn't using the right virtual host and is using the default one.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyRequests off
ServerName main.website.com
ServerAlias www.main.website.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@webmaster.com

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
            # Server ip 1
            BalancerMember http://0.0.0.0:80
            # Server ip2
            BalancerMember http://0.0.0.0:80

            ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions, there are a number of ways to do this -

1. Use DNS - Multiple resource records for the domain, each pointing to a 
   different IP address - it is possible to have multiple A records and
   servers will hand them out in random order, which can provide crude
   load balancing.  You probably want to run low TTL's for this, and 
   it won't work well if there are few systems trying to upload.  This
   does not require anything special though.
2. A more sophisticated variant on the above would be to have your
   nameservers use Split DNS to provide different answers for different
   request - typically based on source IP address.  You need DNS server(s)
   which support multiple views for this - BIND normally springs to mind.
   (Point is, this may not be viable if you are using someone elses
   nameservers)
3. Forget about doing it at DNS - arrange your system into a cluster 
   and use a load balancer in front of it.  This will provide resiliance
   in case systems fail, as well as finer grain control.  Any number
   of systems can do this - Squid, Apache, IPVadm (different approach,
   works at a lower level).   I've not looked at it, but as an 
   alternative, you might be able to use something like Amazons Cloudfront.

Comment: After reading for a while a see that round robin DNS isn't a good solution. Right now i'm trying to configure the main server as a reverse proxy load balancer. It's working somewhat how-ever for some reason the javascripts and css aren't loading? Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've updated the questions with the code i'm using.

Comment: This update really should be a separate question, as it has nothing to do with your original one, and makes it harder for people to find what they are looking for in future.

Comment: You also havn't provided sufficient details to allow us to work out why CSS and javascript is not loading - eg the Apache log files for each server.   I note that you have proxied the root of the server - it may be an idea to exclude static content - which would be standard (ideally only rewrite the paths you need, but otherwise you might be able to do something like ProxyPass /css !    - I observe you do not have any ProxyPassReverse statements - and this could also explain your problem (this statement rewrites your headers).

Comment: The issue with the CSS was resolved as the wrong file path was in the html.